# Querying in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a database of tables Subject, Grade, Chapter and Question. A Subject has many Grade, a Grade and many Chapter, a Chapter has many Question. If I want to perform search all the questions of Subject = Biology, Grade = 4, Chapter = 1, how should I build the query?

My Classes

```
class Subject:Object {
    dynamic var subject_id = 0
    dynamic var subject_name = ""
    let grades = List<Grade>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "subject_id"
    }
}

class Grade:Object {
    dynamic var grade_id = 0
    dynamic var grade_num = 0
    let chapters = List<Chapter>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "grade_id"
    }
}

class Chapter:Object {
    dynamic var chapter_id = 0
    dynamic var chapter_num = 0
    let questions = List<Question>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "chapter_id"
    }
}

class Question:Object {
    dynamic var question_id = 0
    dynamic var question_desc = ""
    dynamic var question_ans = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "question_id"
    }
}
```

So far the only way that I can think of to achieve this is as follows, which I feel that there are way to many nested loops and if else.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let subjects = realm.objects(Subject).filter(NSPredicate(format: "subject_name = %@", "Biology"))

var searched:List<Question>?

for subject in subjects {
    if subject.subject_name == "Biology" {
        for grade in subject.grades {
            if grade.grade_num == 4 {
                for chapter in grade.chapters {
                    if chapter.chapter_num == 1 {
                        searched = chapter.questions
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Realm 0.100 it's possible to use inverse relationships in queries.

So, my suggestion would be to add inverse relationships to your model like this :

```
class Grade:Object {
    dynamic var grade_id = 0
    dynamic var grade_num = 0
    let chapters = List<Chapter>()

    let subjects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Subject.self, property: "grades")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "grade_id"
    }
}

class Chapter:Object {
    dynamic var subject_id = 0
    dynamic var chapter_num = 0
    let questions = List<Question>()

    let grades = LinkingObjects(fromType: Grade.self, property: "chapters")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "subject_id"
    }
}

class Question:Object {
    dynamic var question_id = 0
    dynamic var question_desc = ""
    dynamic var question_ans = ""

    let chapters = LinkingObjects(fromType: Chapter.self, property: "questions")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "question_id"
    }
}
```

Then you can query your model similar to this:

```
let questionsIWant = realm.objects(Question.self)
    .filter("ANY chapters.chapter_num == 3")
    .filter("ANY chapters.grades.grade_num == 1")
    .filter("ANY chapters.grades.subjects.subject_name == 'Biology'")
```